# How to work with django-rest-framework in the templates

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

Please bear with me. I am just learning [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org). And I really can't seem to grab it.

model:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class ToDo(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Day)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    very_important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

normal view:

```
def home(request):
    days = Day.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'test.html', {
        'days':days
    })
```

Created a serializers.py file:

```
class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Day
        field = ('id', 'date')


class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = DaySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        field = ('id', 'date', 'name', 'very_important', 'finished')
```

After this I am lost. Suppose I go to `url('^api/$')`, how do I get the json objects of Day and its related object?

Basically this is how I want to be displayed:

[image]

Now how can I work with django-rest-framework to look like the above in the template.

**update**

I would like to do something like this:

1. Get the json objects by going to a url (eg: /api/.json)

   ```
   [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "date": "2015-06-23",
           "day_todo_set": [
               {
                   "id":5
                   "name": "Bloom",
                   "very_important": True,
                   "finished": False
               },
               {
                   "id":4
                   "name": "REST",
                   "very_important": True,
                   "finished": True
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "date": "2015-06-22",
           "day_todo_set": [
               {
                   "id":3
                   "name": "Alarm 1",
                   "very_important": True,
                   "finished": True
               },
               {
                   "id":2
                   "name": "Meet up with SIS",
                   "very_important": True,
                   "finished": False
               },
               {
                   "id":1
                   "name": "Buy Milk",
                   "very_important": True,
                   "finished": False
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
   ```
2. Manipulate objects

js:

```
$(function () {
    var $days = $('#days')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/.json',
        success: function(days) {
            $.each(days, function(i, day) {
                $days.append('<li>date: '+ day.date+ '</li>')
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

model.py:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def get_todo_list(self):
        return self.day_todo_set.order_by('-id')[:5] 

class ToDo(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Day, related_name="day_todo_set")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    very_important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In serializers.py

```
class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        field = ('id', 'date', 'name', 'very_important', 'finished')

class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    day_todo_set = ToDoSerializer(many=True, source="get_todo_list")

    class Meta:
       model = Day
       field = ('id', 'date', 'day_todo_set')
```

Write a django view using your serializer.

```
@csrf_exempt
def day_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Day.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]
        serializer = DaySerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

In your urls.py

```
url(r'^api/$', views.day_list, name='days_list')
```

Comment: Why did you import APIView? And yes its giving me objects of days, but I need each day's todo too. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It is as expected! Thank you. Just one more thing, is there anyway to get only 10 Day objects and 5 ToDo objects, probably in the views?

Comment: `snippets = Day.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]` will return last 10 days objects. if you want last 5 tasks, you can write custom methods on your Day model which `return self. days_list.order_by('-id')[:5]` and update your serializer with `day_todo_set = ToDoSerializer(many=True, source="methed_name")`

Comment: Would you please update the answer with your comment, it will be helpful for other users too. And thanks again.

Comment: Updated, now you can try.

Answer (score 2):

rest framework is not aimed to serve html that is displayed in a browser. It is aimed to serve data to another service (a mobile device, an heavy client, an other server, etc.)

First line of the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/):

> Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit that makes it
>   easy to build Web APIs.

If you want to display the result in a browser, use templates and do not use rest

Comment: Yes, I know. That's what I want. Suppose I want it in json format, and if I go to `url('^api/$')`, how to I get list of Days and its related object?

Comment: Yes. I think that's it. Will you please look at my updates and guide me how to. Thank you.

Comment: There's no reason why both shouldn't be usable. Having a browser solution that accepts/provides other sources/consumers with data via json has lots of use cases. This isn't a one-or-the-other scenario.